# SSRS DateTime Parameters DefaultValue Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, reporting-services

I have an asp.net application that allows users to create subscriptions for SSRS reports.

All my reports  have @StartDate and @EndDate parameters which have default values of

```
=Today.AddDays(-14)
```

and

```
=Today
```

respectively.

My c# code takes checks the defaultvalue of the parameters when loading the subscription form, to pre-populate AspxDateEdit controls.  This all works fine on my dev environment (NZ).

```
        ItemParameter[] Parameters = _Rs.GetItemParameters(_ThisReportPath, null, true, null, null);
        if (Parameters.Any())
        {
            foreach (ItemParameter Rp in Parameters)
            {
                if (Rp.ParameterTypeName == "DateTime" && Rp.PromptUser)
                {
                    var MyDtControl = new ASPxDateEdit
                    {
                        ID = "dtParam" + MyTable.Rows.Count
                    };
                    DateTime MyFormattedDisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Rp.DefaultValues[0], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
                    MyDtControl.Date = MyFormattedDisplayDate.Date;
                }
            }
        }
```

The initial website will be residing on a server in Australia, with subsequent rollouts to various countries around the world, so I need to keep the format of DateTimes dynamic (Culture specific).

When loading the subscription form for a report on the live system I get the error “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.”  Dumping the values of the Parameter.DefaultValues[0] shows that the default value on the AU server is in US form (**MM/dd/yyyy**) which is causing the errors. Logging code:

```
SQLReportsLogic.Log(MyLog, "(Line 599 - LoadParams)Default Param Value:" + Rp.DefaultValues[0] + "/ ServerDateFormatToday:" + DateTime.Now);
```

Resulting output:

```
(Line 599 - LoadParams)Default Param Value:3/24/2015 12:00:00 AM/ ServerDateFormatToday:24/03/2015 7:14:47 AM
```

The format is expected to align with the culture info of the server which would be **dd/MM/yyyy**.

```
-   The report language is set to User!Language
-   The Server System Locale is English(Australia)
-   The Server Location is Australia
-   The Server Datetime format is set to ShortDate=d/MM/yyyy LongDate=dddd, d MMMM yyyy
-   The Server Language is set to English (Australia)
-   The Reporting Services Service is running under Local System Account
-   WWW is running under Local System Account
-   SSRS is running in Native Mode
```

Where specifically does SSRS get the DateTime Format from when determining the format for =Today()?  As I understand my research to date, this should be generating =Today() in the system assigned format of dd/MM/yyyy
I have also tried formatting the DefaultValue of the parameters to

```
-   “yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss” = The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘StartDate’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format
-   “yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm” = The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘StartDate’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format
-   “yyyy/MM/dd” = The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘StartDate’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format
-   DateFormat.ShortDate = The property ‘DefaultValue’ of report parameter ‘StartDate’ doesn’t have the expected type.
-   DateFormat.LongDate = The property ‘DefaultValue’ of report parameter ‘StartDate’ doesn’t have the expected type.
-   DateFormat.GeneralDate = The property ‘DefaultValue’ of report parameter ‘StartDate’ doesn’t have the expected type.
```

It would seem that unless I can resolve the way SSRS renders =Today() that my hands are tied.  As I understand it I need to find the issue with the SSRS installation using the incorrect Culture?  Is it looking it up in the registry somewhere?

I am using VS2012 (11.0.61030.00 Update 4) with SSDTBI Plugin (MSSQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 11.0.3436.0)

Comment: Can we see the code that throws this `FormatException`? And what is your culture settings?

Comment: Thanks Soner,  I have added code to the question, my culture is set to neutral in web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the right search terms to use and found a solution after two days - to override the SSRS GetWebRequest as described here.. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f147c641-d5c2-49e8-97f6-b654bec8366d/datetime-format-for-webservice-api-calls?forum=sqlreportingservices#0c223835-dd5c-4471-b736-1d9dad014144

```
public partial class ReportingService : DevReportService.ReportingService2010
{

    /// <summary>

    /// Gets or sets the culture that is used when generating the report.

    /// </summary>

    /// <value>The culture that is used when generating the report.</value>

    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {

        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        CultureInfo culture = this.Culture ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, culture.Name);

        return request;

    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer! An enhancement to this would be to create a new class that has DevReportService.ReportingService2010 as a parent, in the off chance that your WSDL CS file is regenerated at all in the future